# How to auto link dependencies of a dependency in React Native?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I want to share components of one app with the other and therefore moved them to a separate NPM package. The structure of this package looks like this:

```
- src
--- components
----- component A
----- component B
- package.json
```

Some components use other 3rd party libraries and they are listed in the `package.json`.

Now when installing that shared package to the second project these 3rd party dependencies are not auto linked. For example, when calling `pod install` they're not installed.

Is it possible somehow install these 3rd party dependencies?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this? I ran into the same issue, but there's 0 documentation to be found on this.

Comment: @Anwardo unfortunately not. For now, I just added a new README section to the shared package with instructions on what dependencies to install (link) manually.

Comment: Thanks for your response! After getting really annoyed I ended up doing the same and specifying my dependencies as peerDependencies. Hopefully the RN team will add autolinking for nested dependencies at some point.

Comment: Before RN 60 you could use react-native link 'name-of-the-project' .. But now you got -> Unknown dependency. Make sure that the package you are trying to link is already installed in your "node_modules" and present in your "package.json" dependencies.

Comment: @febaisi I tried that before posting my question but unfortunately, that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can patch function findDependencies in @react-native-community/cli as follow to enable auto link dependencies of dependency

```
function findDependencies(root) {
  let pjson;

  try {
    pjson = JSON.parse(_fs().default.readFileSync(_path().default.join(root, 'package.json'), 'UTF-8'));
  } catch (e) {
    return [];
  }

  const dependencies = Object.keys(pjson.dependencies || []);
  const subDeps = dependencies.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
    if (!currentValue.includes('your_dependency')) {
      return accumulator;
    }
    const subRoot = `${root}/node_modules/${currentValue}`;
    return accumulator.concat(findDependencies(subRoot));
  }, []);

  const deps = [...Object.keys(pjson.dependencies || {}), ...Object.keys(pjson.devDependencies || {}), ...subDeps];
  return deps;
}
```

Comment: I don't need to install dependencies like this anymore but when tested on the old repo it worked like a charm :) Thanks!